# Render children pages in umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco, parent-child

I'm trying to make an FAQ page. The content structure is like this:

- FAQ
  -- Question 1
  -- Question 2
  -- Question 3

I can't seem to work out how to get the child templates to render though (I'm new to this).

FAQ Entries (Parent page)

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    Layout = null;
    var faqContentId = (int)CurrentPage.faqContent;
}

<html>
    @Html.Partial("head")
    <body>
        @Html.Partial("header")

        <div class="content">
            @{
                foreach (var child in Umbraco.Content(1168).Children) {
                    // render children here
                }
            }
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("footer")
    </body>
</html>
```

FAQ Entry (Child pages)

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                @Umbraco.Field("title")
            </button>
        </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
            @Umbraco.Field("answer")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome my dear Umbraco Dev. Let me point you to a few directions:

If you only want the solution, skip to number 3.

1) Refrain from using `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage` as it will soon be deprecated. Use `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage` instead which will get you strongly typed stuff in your view and your code will look like @Model.GetPropertyValue("myValue")

Even better, create a custom model or try using [Umbraco ModelsBuilder](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/getting-started-with-modelsbuilder/)

which will get you cleaner code and stronger bindings with strongly typed models. But that's for another day.

2) I would recommend not grabbing nodes by id `Umbraco.Content('id').Children` like this. The reason is that if you for some reason delete the node and then create it again later on with the same name, the id will be different and your code will break the website.

Look at this page where people pointed me to the correct way of traversing umbraco [Umbraco traversing](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/92266-is-traversing-umbraco-slow)

It talks about speed but it basically shows you also the correct way to traverse. you could also find the rest you need within Umbraco's documentation.

**3)To the actual question:** I'm assuming that the page you're on is the parent and you just want to grab the children. Then it's as easy as :

```
var collection = Model.Content.Children();
@foreach (var child in collection ) {

    child.GetPropertyValue("yourValueAliasHere")
}
```

if you were using `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage` you would have:

```
var collection = Model.Children();
@foreach (var child in Model.Children()) {

    child.GetPropertyValue("yourValueAliasHere")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like @Html.Partial("FAQ Entry", child), where the 2nd parameter is the model (child object) that you want to pass into the partial view.